# What is the use of eosio.code?

Tags: cleos, eosio-code, authority

Some major questions I have:

- What does `eosio.code` mean?
- When do we require `eosio.code`?
- Why it is not mentioned in the official EOSIO developer's documentation?

Comment: do you mean the `eosio.code` permission?

Comment: yeah @confused00

Comment: it mentioned in eosio developers doc https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/inline-actions#section-step-1-adding-eosiocode-to-addressbooks-account

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to official documentation:  https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/getting-started/smart-contract-development/adding-inline-actions/#step-1-adding-eosiocode-to-permissions

Answer (score 1):

## What does eosio.code mean?

`eosio.code` is a special permission that can be used to allow the smart contract to call an action without the authorization of a specific user. It is used to allow smart contracts to call inline actions.

## When do we require eosio.code?

You need to include the `eosio.code` permission on any smart contract that will be calling inline actions. Usually it is added as an additional permission to the active key permission, you can do this several ways:

### Using cleos with --add-code

```
cleos set account permission CONTRACT active --add-code -p CONTRACT
```

### Using cleos without --add-code

This assumes that you have a simple key running on active permission, if this isn't the case then the JSON payload has to be adjusted accordingly.

```
cleos set account permission CONTRACT active '{"threshold":1, "keys":[{"key":"YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE", "weight":1}], "accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"CONTRACT","permission":"eosio.code"}, "weight":1}], "waits":[]}' owner -p CONTRACT
```

## Why is it not mentioned in the documentation

It is, but perhaps it wasn't at the time of posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are mentioning about eosio.code please refer to this.

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/3013#issuecomment-388983168